# Accurately updating LastUpdatedOn datetime2 column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, azure-sql-database, change-data-capture

I want to update `LastUpdatedOn datetime2` column every time a row is updated in a SQL Server table. To accomplish this, I was thinking of using an `After Update` trigger to set `LastUpdatedOn` to `sysutcdatetime()`. This trigger is also responsible for detecting column changes and saving the old values to a history table. My question is, will the trigger approach save an accurate representation of the time a row is updated? Is there a time delay between an actual update vs. `After Update` trigger updating `LastUpdatedOn`?

Also, reading http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx, it looks like `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` may not be accurate across multiple servers. In a sharded database architecture with a lot of concurrent writes, what's the most reliable way to detect event times so that I know the order of events across the whole cluster is correct?

P.S. I've thought about using `Change Data Capture`, but it's not available in SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a delay, depending on how many rows you're updating in a single statement and how log as it takes, because the trigger is fired at the very end. I would recommend updating the time inside the actual update statement.

Moreover, use output clause to move data to history table.